# "Editor invited" to "Decision in Process"

Tags: peer-review, editors, rejection

I submitted my paper to World Scientific journal for a week ago. The "Editor invited" status stayed since the submission, and then it changed to "Decision in Process" directly. It seems strange. Normally “editor invited” comes after manuscript screening. Why was there no "with editor" status and why did it change to "Decision in Process"?

Comment: Answers in comments and discussion about the reputability of World Scientific have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107446/discussion-on-question-by-nourr-mga-editor-invited-to-decision-in-process).

Answer (score 3):

It means they're making a decision without peer review. Usually not a good sign; a desk rejection is very likely.

If you're asking why "with editor" didn't show up, there's a good chance it did, but the editor made a decision in a few minutes and you didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this journal sends out invitations to the editor as soon as a manuscript is submitted, and an admin person conducts the manuscript screening while waiting for the editor to accept the invitation. This could be a way of speeding up the process, and is probably the reason for the status change to “decision in process.